# Microphone of a bluetooth headset not get audio in ubuntu

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

I am new to ubuntu. And recently I installed the ubuntu 23.04 in my laptop lenovo ideapad 320. After some search, I figured out how to set up the bluetooth headset, installed bluez and blueman, but I still cannot figure out how to setup the microphone for my bluetooth headset. The microphone is detected, but when I selected it, no sound is detected by the microphone